# Different behavior of member variable with -O2 and without

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization

With -O2, someone told me that the value of A will be always zero as gcc will init B and C to zero? Why? However, as expected, wihtout -O2, the value of A will be undefined due to the incorrect init order.

```
#include <iostream>

class ClassX
{
public:
    ClassX() : C_(1), B_(2), A_(B_ + C_) {};
    void print() {std::cout << A_ << std::endl;}    
private:
    int A_;
    int B_;
    int C_;
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    ClassX x;
    x.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should ask that someone to provide you with a reference from the GCC documentation.

Comment: The initialize order is the order they are declared. so A is initialized first. so your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: Even if that were true, that's pretty unactionable. You'd still get fired for writing code like this.

Comment: I hope that someone is compiling with `-Wall`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice to write an initializer list that contains this kind of initialization inter-dependencies, since this requires specific data member declaration order. In this case, consider writing it this way:

```
 ClassX() : C_(1), B_(2) { A_ = B_ + C_; }
```

Also, zero-initialization of data members is not guaranteed by all compilers. A zero-fill *may* occur for the page where your data is to be located during process load, but again, this is not guaranteed and is OS-specific. For debug builds, your memory will most likely be filled with non-zero values.